# Swift 2 iOS 9 File reading not line-by-line

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, filereader, file-read

I need to be able to read/write to a file without loading the whole file into memory but instead skipping around and reading the parts I need. I can not seem to find a solution that is not a line by line read of the file.How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Apple Developer documentation for NSFileHandle, and read about "Seeking Within a File", using offsetInFile, seekToEndOfFile, and so on.  You can jump to any location within a file and read the contents, but of course you will need to know what is there, or else you might misinterpret the data.